overflow is not working to hide translated element
I am trying to hide the translated element using overflow: hidden but it is not working.
The CSS overflow property hides content exceeding an element's boundaries. When elements are translated (e.g., using transform: translate()), they might move outside their container, causing them to be hidden if overflow is set to hide. Please help me.
import React from 'react';
import "../styles.css"
const Header = () => {

    const NavToggle = ()=>{
        const element = document.getElementById('myUl');
        if(element.classList.contains("active")){
            element.classList.remove('active')
        }
        else{
            element.classList.add('active')
        }
    }

return (
    <header  id='myUl' className='header flex gap-12'>
        <h1>Logo</h1>
        <nav className='navbar'>
            <ul className='nav-list flex gap-4'>
                <li><a className='nav-link' href='#'>Home</a></li>
                <li><a className='nav-link' href='#'>about</a></li>
                <li><a className='nav-link' href='#'>contact us</a></li>
                <li><a className='nav-link' href='#'>login</a></li>
                <li><a className='nav-link' href='#'>signup</a></li>
            </ul>     
        </nav>
            
        <div className='cursor-pointer icon' onClick={NavToggle}>
            <i className="fa-solid fa-bars"></i>
            <i className="fa-solid fa-xmark close"></i>
        </div>    
    </header>
)}

export default Header

CSS:
html{
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: 62.5%;
}

body {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.header{
    padding: 0 4.8rem;
    height: 10rem;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: rgb(179, 245, 245);
    width: 100vw;
    overflow: hidden;
}
@media (max-width:640px){
    .navbar{
        z-index: 20;
        background: rgb(165, 143, 143);
        height: 95vh;
        width: 30%;
        top: 0;
        position: absolute;
        display: flex;
        text-align: center;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        right: 0;
        margin-top: 4rem;
        border-radius: 20%;
        transform: translateX(100%);
        transition: all 0.3s linear;
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }
    .nav-list{
        flex-direction: column; 
    }
    .icon{
        display: block;
    }
    .header.active .navbar{
        transform: translateX(0); 
    }
    .active .icon .close{
        position: absolute;
        display: block;
        z-index: 100; 
    }
}


Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a Stack Snippet using the <> icon.  See How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example
